# Legacy Data Integration

Tags: powerbi

beginner here,

I have a file of legacy data that I need to integrate into my power bi data.

The new data architecture is quite different in the sense that the legacy file has data that need to be split into different tables.

Example:

Table A is my legacy file. B, C, and D are tables in my new architecture.

For a given row in A, columns A1, A2, and A3 contains equivalent information to B1, C5, and D3 respectively.

So I am trying to get a sense of the best way to integrated Table A.

Is there a way to dynamically tell Power BI that columns A2 and C5 contain the same information so that when I add one or the other in a report, it automatically takes both?
Should just manually add new rows in each table and add the information from table A?

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is no way in Power BI to do this automatically. This is something, that you should do in your data model (i.e. to build a common data model, e.g. in Analysis Services, which to be used in your reports). But if you want to combine these tables in a single Power BI report, then you can do this using `Append Queries` command to combine the data from the old and new tables:

[image]

You should also take a look at [Tutorial: Shape and combine data in Power BI Desktop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-shape-and-combine-data) article.